# Angular controller called twice. How to know the number of instantiations

Tags: angularjs, controller, instantiation, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller

Is a controller instantiated a second time when I declare the controller in two different `<div>`s? I just want to know if the controller will be loaded twice or not like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the controller will run once for each `ng-controller` attribute. If you have `ng-controller` inside `ng-repeat`, the controller will run once for each row. If you have `ng-controller` inside `ng-if`, the controller will run every time the condition changes from `false` to `true`.